# How to use spring transaction in multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, transactional, propagation

I have a method as below:

```
ClassA.java
@Transactional
public void methodA(){        
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            classB.methodB();
        }
});
}
ClassB.java
@Transactional
public void methodB(){
    updateDB();
}
```

Can the methodB work well? Per my understanding, methodB will attach the transaction of methodA, what if methodA exits before methodB? I guess only methodA can be commited by the transaction. But methodB will not commit because the transaction commited before.

Can I use @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) for methodB. This can let methodB have a new transaction. But according to spring doc, the transcation of methodA will suspend when it invoke methodB. I feel very confuse here.

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, `methodB()` will not be executed in the same transaction as `methodA()`. Spring's `@Transactional` only works on a single thread - it creates a session when a thread first enteres a method with `@Transactional` (or a method in a class with `@Transactional`), and then commits it when it leaves that method.

In your example, the transaction will end after you schedule the job in the thread pool. `methodB()` will have it's own transaction.

Comment: Can you advise how to monitor if they are not the same transaction? What I found was that the transaction was not commit.

Comment: @Jacky Which of the two transactions does not commit?

Comment: Transaction of methodB does not commit.

Comment: I can't really know what is the problem, but a wild guess would be that ClassB is not a Spring bean - see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained

Comment: It is a Spring bean. It worked well after I made it excuting in the same thread which means I removed the use of executorService.

Comment: @Jacky Sorry, no more ideas - if you could post more about your transaction manager, spring beans, and classes, maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Kiril. I tried @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) but it did not work either. Spring itself provides Task Executor. I did not use it. I just create Executor on my own, I'm not sure if it does matter. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: It's my bad. Kiril, you are right. It will create a new transaction for the new thread. Another bug caused the problem which misled me.